# Query approximate in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to query an approximate in python dataframes?
So for this example I could be interested in the value in column `Y` with the value closest to `2` in column `X` which should give me "f" and/or "w".
See the example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({  
'X': [1,3,4,6,8,12,15,23,22,32],  
'Y': ['f', 'w', 'fsssa', 'ddf', 'wq', 'h', 'wss', 'rrh', 'ddw', 'e4']
})
```

Comment: Querying a range could also be very helpful!

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question, because i think I know what the intention is and already tried to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two steps as follows:

```
query_value=2 # the value, you want to query for
# calculate the absolute distance to the query value
ser_abs= (df['X']-query_value).abs()
# filter the rows for the rows with the minimum distance
df[ser_abs == ser_abs.min()]
```

This evaluates to:

```
   X  Y
0  1  f
1  3  w
```

If you are only interested in the Y-Values the last line is:

```
df.loc[ser_abs == ser_abs.min(), 'Y']
```